What does the ellipsis in the type hint "-> None: ..." mean
Here is an example from the pandas package:
class NDFrameIndexerBase(Generic[_IndexingMixinT]):
    name: str
    # in practice obj is either a DataFrame or a Series
    obj: _IndexingMixinT

    def __init__(self, name: str, obj: _IndexingMixinT) -> None: ...
    @property
    def ndim(self) -> int: ...

I get -> returns none, and I get list["str",...] means list of arbitrary amounts of strings, but this doesn't make sense for None or Int

The type of the output of a function. e.g.,  the output of __init__ is None type. The output of ndim method is int type. see here

It's used to indicate the function is not defined. Same as putting pass in the function definition block. It's not part of the type hint.

As far as I know, ellipsis is commonly used in the body for type stubs, where the implementation is irrelevant, and pass is used when “pass” is the implementation (i.e. it really does do nothing).

@dragoncoder047 I think that gives me the complete information on what it is and when/why to use it.  you should put it in an answer

"list["str",...] means list of arbitrary amounts of strings" - Where did you get that from? A list of strings is just list[str]. According to Mypy, list["str", ...] isn't valid: error: "list" expects 1 type argument, but 2 given
